Meanders and Rainbows
I recently watched this online lecture by the late mathematician Maryam Mirzakhani, and I was quite intrigued by the first problem related to combinatorics she presented in the video (the one with drawing rainbows and counting number of connected components). I was wondering if there is any existing literature on this problem, whether its been "solved", or even the name of the problem.

Put $2n$ points on an interval, spaced $1$ apart, on $1,2,\dots 2n$ on the $x$-axis. Draw semicircles between opposite points to form a "rainbow" in $(1, 2n)$ in the upper half plane. (That is, connect $1$ and $2n$, connect $2$ and $2n-1$, ...).
Write $n=a_1+\dots + a_k$ for fixed $k$. Starting with $i=1$ on the left, for each $i$, draw rainbows of radius $a_i$ in the lower half plane. That is, a rainbow in $(1, 2a_1)$, then a rainbow in $(1+2a_1, 2a_1+2a_2)$, ..., then finally a rainbow in $(1+ 2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i, 2n)$.
Call the resulting shape $S(a_1, \dots, a_k)$.

When the result is connected, it is called a meander.
How many connected components? Seems that $k=2$ is simple but after that it becomes complicated. Is there a $c>0$ such that as $n\to\infty$, such that $c\%$ of shapes are connected?

@nonuser Meanders are an extremely popular topic of research in recent years. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05190, https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.02319, etc.
